# React Native If there is a token, how can I close the application without entering the login page again on Android?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
  const onSubmit = async (values: { username: string; password: string }) => {
    const credentials = await Keychain.getGenericPassword();
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      login(values, {
        onSuccess: data => {
          resolve(undefined);
          dispatch(
            auth({
              user: true,
              token: data?.data,
            }),
          );
          if (!credentials) {
            Keychain.setGenericPassword(email, password);
          }
          console.log('tokennn:', data);
          axiosConfig(data?.data);
          setEmail('')
          setPassword('')
          setTimeout(() => {
            props.navigation.navigate(SCREEN.tab);
          }, 600);
        },
        onError: error => {
          reject;
          Toast.error("Giriş Başarısız", "E-posta adresinizi veya şifrenizi hatalı girdiniz.")
        },
      });
    });
  };
```

I am using tab navigator in android environment.
Every time I press the back button on android, it comes back and comes back to the sign up page. How can I prevent this?
I want it to close the application without entering the sign up page.
To do this, do not show this page again on a return if there is a token.

Comment: You can store data using https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage  after login and on application start, you can skip the login screen and redirect to a particular screen.

Comment: Take a look at Authentication flows: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow.